# Half of electrical circuits remain out after exterior neutral failure

Tags: electrical, wiring

Half electric works in house.  Had broken neutral wire outside on house.  Had electrician change all wiring from power company to meter then from meter to breaker box and put a new breaker box in and still have same problem.

Everything was fine until wire outside came loose.  What could the problem be?  Any help much appreciated.  Checked outlets and switches and lights and ceiling fans. See no problem there. Thank you.

Comment: Did the electrician tell you *why* they chose to replace the entire service from the pole to the breaker box?  If you lost a phase from the utility *they* should be looking into why.

Comment: ComEd came out and said the wires from the pole to the house were fine,  It was from after it got to the house, very old wires not in conduit, had to have a new service drop, old meter box, and old breaker box,  There is 240 at wires coming in and 120 to all breakers and neutral .

Comment: When you say "half of the house" do you mean the circuits on one side of the breaker box?  I'd try cutting the 240 breakers one at a time (stove, A/C, etc.) to see if isolating the buses helps.

Comment: No, the kitchen works, the basement works and upstairs works,  Half my bedroom, my daughters room, front room and bathroom have no power

Comment: Why are you asking us and not the electrician you paid to resolve the issue?

Comment: Because he changed what he needed to change, but to look into it further he would charge more that we don't have right now, so I would like to see if I can fix it myself if I can pinpoint where the problem is

Comment: This doesn't sound like a DIY situation with respect to your safety.

Comment: Well cant afford to call the guy back so If I have to figure it out and fix it myself I will

Comment: I am careful and use my meter so as not to get zapped, believe me I am careful

Comment: The most common mistake is trying to "get by" with the knowledge you have, and not get more knowledge.  Hit the library... hard... and devour all the books you can on home electrical.  Overlearn and overskill yourself, so you know all the angles.  Dare I say it... Knowledge is power!

Answer (score 1):

If 1/2 work probably L1 or L2 leg on the supply side or main bkr has failed this will cause every other bkr on the left and every other on the right to not have power. I replaced a 200a main a few years back that had this problem although I like square d this was the first time I have seen this and 1 more from Eaton since then. The power from the feeder needs to be checked prior to the main and after. Sounds like you have an Electrician doing some of the work but some states in the U.S. Have very lax rules and not much training. If one of the legs have failed that may account for 1/2 of things not working. Do you have 220? Like for a dryer or electric range? If not your power to the new panel is probably the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The original question seems to suggest one leg is not connected.  But the comments clarify that 240 volt appliances still work.

This happened so long ago, the OP must have identified the cause by now.  But I would open the panel and see if all the buses are connected.  If half don't work, then the connection from the main breaker to one of the sides must be broken.